# function is returning before the API service is being called iOS

Tags: ios, swift, function

I am trying to return the "cardsarray" which contain the name, designation, and 4 more fields. When API is being called it returns the array of object which gets stored into my array.

But when I run the application doesn't show anything in the table view.

I tried some print statement. It came out that the function is returning before the API is being called. Not able to understand why. Please help

[image]

```
 {
    designation = "Manager";
    email = "Sample@gmail.com";
    mobile =1234567899;
    name = "Sample";
    status = 0;
    Company = "ABC Corp"

},
    {
    "pending_staff_pic" = 1;
}
```

Comment: You are missing the concept of Asynchronism. Look for "Swift + Closure + Async" to know how manage it.

Comment: Never include code as a screenshot in your question. Include it as text using proper code formatting.

Comment: better use completion handler to get insured that the statement is executed.

Comment: @DávidPásztor  I will make sure to add code snippet next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Larne, you need to understand the `asynchronous calls`.

First you need to have a `completion block` in your function like this :

```
func getCards(completion: @escaping (([Cards]) -> Void)) {

}
```

The after your for loop where you are printing cardsArray you need to write this completion block.

```
completion(dataArray)
```

And this is how you have to call this fucntion :

```
getCards { (cardsArray) in

}
```

Comment: thank you, brother, for your help. I got the code working.